# Graph containing node structure with two pointers

Tags: c, graph-theory

I am trying to write a simple graph for storing sizes of created tables. I am new to C so I am sorry if I miss some simple pointer operations.

My graph is containing `prev`ious and `next` pointers, where first `next` will point to the last node and serve as a iterator to grab `next->next`. I don't want to store any more information then those two pointers and size of the graph, so one can reach the nodes only trough the iteration of `next` pointer.

Here is a minimal reproducible example of my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct GC {
  uint data;
  uint size;
  struct GC *next;
  struct GC *prev;
};

void build_gc_root(struct GC **self) {
  // Build root node
  printf("Allocating gc.\n");
  struct GC *tmp = malloc(sizeof *tmp);
  tmp->size = 0;
  tmp->data = 666;
  tmp->prev = tmp;
  tmp->next = tmp;
  printf("Saving allocation of gc.\n");
  (*self) = tmp;
}

void gc_clean(struct GC **self) {
  uint _;
  printf("Cleaning the gc table.\n");
  for (_ = 0; _ < (*self)->size + 1; ++_) {
    printf("Free node %hd.\n", (*self)->next->next->data);
    free((*self)->next->next);
    ++(*self)->next;
  }
  printf("Free last node %hd.\n", (*self)->next->data);
  free((*self)->next);
}

void gc_store(struct GC **self, uint data) {
  printf("Storing GC value node.\n");
  (*self)->next = malloc(sizeof *(*self)->next);
  (*self)->next->data = data;
  (*self)->next->prev = (*self)->prev;
  (*self)->next->next = (*self);
  (*self)->prev = (*self)->next;
  ++(*self)->size;
}

typedef struct {
  void (*clean)();
  void (*get_size)(uint size);
  void (*print_table)();
  struct GC *gc;
}__controller;

__controller controller;

void controller_clean() {
  gc_clean(&controller.gc);
}

void controller_get_size(uint size) {
  gc_store(&controller.gc, size);
}

void controller_print_table() {
  uint index;
  printf("GC catch: \n");
  for (index = 0; index < controller.gc->size + 1; ++index) {
    printf("  %hd\n", controller.gc->next->next->data);
    --controller.gc->next;
  }
  putchar('\n');
}

__controller controller = {
  controller_clean, controller_get_size, controller_print_table
};

int main (void) {
  build_gc_root(&controller.gc);
  controller.get_size(1);
  controller.get_size(2);
  controller.get_size(3);
  controller.print_table();
  controller.clean();
  return 0;
}
```

After running this, the `controller.print_table()` method will output only two first node's data and end up with segmentation fault.

Comment: `(*self)->next = malloc(sizeof self);` This allocates memory with size of a pointer while `next` points to a struct element. You should use `sizof (struct GC)` or sizeof (*(*self)->next)`

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `--controller.gc->next;`

Comment: Also `++(*self)->next;` looks fishy. You don't allocate arrays. Pointer arithmetics is only allowed within the boundaries of one data object, i.e. an array. Also this line is completely useless because you assign `(*self)->next` a new value in the next line

Comment: `--controller.gc->next`, lets `controller.gc->next->next` iterate. Yes, you are right, `++(*self)->next` is useless in this context.

Comment: What do you mean by "iterate"? You make pointer `next` now point to `&next[1]`. You never allocate memory for more than 1 element for `next`.

Comment: Well, I thought I have interconnected this graph, so this should point to the next allocated by `gc_store()` structure.

Comment: You mean, I need to allocate an array to store those addresses? Is it that not possible to do by just using pointers?

Comment: `++` operator on a pointer incremens by 1 element. It does not follow links inside the struct where the pointer points to. If you want to follow the list, you need to use `next->next` which might then point to exactly that address that you `free` a few lines above.

Comment: Ok, but is there a way to iterate trough those connections without hard-coding thing like, `next->next->next` and so on?

Comment: You might add some drawing (may ASCII art) how you intent to construct your graph/list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229264/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-daniel-freeman).

Comment: @DanielFreeman A pointer is like a street address. If you want a house on a given street is all you do just add 1 to the street address? No, you only could do that if you already owned several adjacent lots. Otherwise, you have to purchase the lot and build the house first. Only then you can have a street address that points to it, and the address is then valid. C doesn't prevent you from writing bogus street addresses but they don't make the imaginary house become reality anymore than it'd happen in real life :) `malloc` buys the land. `memset` or the constructor function builds the house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are creating a stack that is linked via `prev` pointer. The `next` is rather useless and you should think about removing it.

When it comes to printing or deleting the content, you have used wrong mechanism to iterate over your list.

Operators `++` and `--` used on pointers move them to the next/previous consecutive element in memory. This is only valid within an array which you do not use.

Instead you need to follow the links in your structure to reach the next element.

This would look like this:

```c
void gc_clean(struct GC** self) {
    uint _;
    printf("Cleaning the gc table.\n");
    struct GC* gc = (*self)->prev;
    for (_ = 0; _ < (*self)->size; ++_) {
        printf("Free node %hd.\n", gc->data);
        struct GC* tmp = gc;
        gc = gc->prev;
        free(tmp);
    }

    printf("Free last node %hd.\n", gc->data);
    free(gc);
}

void controller_print_table() {
    uint index;
    printf("GC catch: \n");
    struct GC* gc = controller.gc->prev;
    for (index = 0; index < controller.gc->size + 1; ++index) {
        printf("  %hd\n", gc->data);
        gc = gc->prev;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Please note that this also removes the initial element from your stack which you added during creation. Also the pointers of your `controller.gc` are not valid any more. You need to initialize again after cleaning the list.

As a side node, you should think about naming.
The function to add an element to your stack, is called `get_size` which is confusing to put it mildly...

Comment: I have also updated the gc_store to use an internal initializer in stead of the weird `next` pointer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I post the working code bellow in case someone wanna see a working stack:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Garbage collector stack
struct GC {
  uint data;
  uint size;
  struct GC *prev;
};

void build_gc_root(struct GC **self) {
  // Build root node
  printf("Allocating gc.\n");
  struct GC *tmp = malloc(sizeof *tmp);
  tmp->size = 0;
  tmp->data = 666;
  tmp->prev = tmp;
  printf("Saving allocation of gc.\n");
  (*self) = tmp;
}

void gc_clean(struct GC **self) {
  uint _;
  printf("Cleaning the gc table.\n");
  struct GC *gc = (*self)->prev;
  for (_ = 0; _ < (*self)->size; ++_) {
    printf("Free node %hd\n", gc->data);
    struct GC* tmp = gc;
    gc = gc->prev;
    free(tmp);
  }
  printf("Free the last node %hd\n", gc->data);
  free(gc);
}

void gc_store(struct GC **self, uint data) {
  printf("Storing GC value node.\n");
  struct GC *node;
  node = malloc(sizeof *(*self)->prev);
  node->data = data;
  node->prev = (*self)->prev;
  (*self)->prev = node;
  ++(*self)->size;
}

void gc_print(struct GC *self) {
  uint index;
  struct GC *gc = self->prev`;
  printf("GC catch: ");
  for (index = 0; index < self->size + 1; ++index) {
    printf(" %hd", gc->data);
    gc = gc->prev;
  }
  putchar('\n');
}

typedef struct {
  void (*clean)();
  void (*get_size)(uint size);
  void (*print_table)();
  struct GC *gc;
}__controller;

__controller controller;

void controller_clean() {
  gc_clean(&controller.gc);
}

void controller_get_size(uint size) {
  gc_store(&controller.gc, size);
}

void controller_print_table() {
  gc_print(controller.gc);
}

__controller controller = {
  controller_clean, controller_get_size, controller_print_table
};

int main (void) {
  build_gc_root(&controller.gc);
  controller.get_size(1);
  controller.get_size(2);
  controller.get_size(3);
  controller.print_table();
  controller.clean();
  return 0;
}
```